# PyQt depth of QTextEdit buffer

Tags: qt, pyqt, buffer, qtextedit, qtextbrowser

I'm using a PyQt QTextBrowser widget that inherits from QTextEdit.  I'm appending text to it as part of a display of logging information.  The logging may go on for weeks.

What is the depth of the buffer that holds the text?  Asked another way, how much text can I append and still have the user be able to scroll back to with the scroll bars?

Is this setting configurable?  Could it eventually use all my system's ram?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There is no automatic management of the size of the text: it will just grow until the available memory runs out.

The simplest solution would probably be to set a fixed limit on the number of text blocks in the document:

```
logger.document().setMaximumBlockCount(5000)
```

This will start deleting blocks from the start of the document once the threshold has been passed. You will obviously have to work out for yourself what a safe maximum will be and/or make it a user-configurable setting.

Note that if you don't need rich-text formatting for the logging output, a [QPlainTextEdit](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qplaintextedit.html) might be a better choice, since it is designed for exactly this sort of task.